# Why VC++/MFC don't have main function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I start learning VC++/MFC. then I created a "HelloWord" program, 
I got two `App.h/.cpp AppDlg.h/.cpp` basic files by created a basic `Dialog` project.

The first problem: I can't find the program entry. there is no `main.cpp` in the project.

Then I tried to find the relationship between `App` and `AppDlg`, met the second problem: base on the file name, looks like `AppDlg` should be a customized MFC `Dialog` component, and the `App` supposes to be the main event thread. But I got below in both `.cpp` files. it included each other. I thought `AppDlg` should be the part of `App`.

```
#include "App.h"
#include "AppDlg.h"
```

these two problem makes me confused about the structure of the project.

Why MFC code looks so different? For what purpose do like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you don't have a "main" function (quoted because it's not *actually* called `main`<sup>(a)</sup>) is because the code has already been written *for* you. This is quite common in frameworks, where a certain amount of set-up is done before the code you're responsible for actually starts running.

In fact, this is often the case even for situations where you *do* create a `main()`, since there's usually start-up code that's responsible for doing things like turning the arguments into `argc/argc` objects to hand over to your main code (if you ever see an object file like [`crt0.o`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) or [`ucrt.lib`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features), that's probably the C run-time start-up code).

In the early days of Windows, the code you wrote had a `WinMain()` function<sup>(a)</sup> which was called by the start-up code in lieu of `main()`, and it was typically responsible for registering window classes, creating and starting message pumps, and all sorts of other stuff which is usually identical in every application. So, by moving that work to a framework of some description, it greatly reduces the amount of code you need to write.

In terms of how this works, think of what would happen if the stuff you linked to contained the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return bob(argc, argv);
}
```

Then *your* code would not actually *need* a `main()` function at all. It *would* need a `bob()` function of course and that's very similar to the situation you've discovered: Microsoft has written their own "main" function in the MFC framework which sets up things so that MFC will work.

Admittedly, my bob-based framework doesn't provide as much benefit as MFC but it's only meant to be an example of how it can be done :-)

---

In terms of what goes into each file created by each project type, [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcw45t5d.aspx) may help. For example, the two files you mentioned are covered by:

- `<projname>`.h : the main include file for the program or DLL. It contains all global symbols and `#include` directives for other header files. It derives the `C<projname>App` class from `CWinApp` and declares an `InitInstance` member function. For a control, the `C<projname>App` class is derived from `COleControlModule`.
- `<projname>dlg.cpp` and `<projname>dlg.h` : created if you choose a dialog-based application. The files derive and implement the dialog class, named `C<projname>Dlg`, and include skeleton member functions to initialise a dialog and perform dialog data exchange (DDX). Your About dialog class is also placed in these files instead of in `<projname>.cpp`.

Note that there's *nothing* in those descriptions about a message pump (for example). That's because all the heavy lifting for that is included in the *base* classes for the things that are created.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The reason why it *wasn't `main()` can be found in [this article on The Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071203-00/?p=24323/) - it was basically to ensure no clash between what the language supplied and what Windows needed.

Comment: Nitpick: I think you had `WinMain`, going back even further than Win32.

Comment: MSalters is correct. `WinMain` was the user-provided entry point in 16-bit Windows as well, back when the second argument (*hPrevInstance*) was actually used.

Comment: Both good points, have researched and adjusted answer to suit.